# Ryzen 7 2700x installing Ubuntu with no integrated graphics shows no signal

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, nvidia-geforce

I have this configuration:

- CPU: Ryzen 7 2700x
- mobo: Asus x470 gaming
- RAM: 2x8GB 3000 MHz
- GPU: GeForce GT 1030
- Monitor: 4K LG monitor

I downloaded the latest stable version of Ubuntu and I made a bootable USB drive with Rufus.

I restarted the PC (with Windows 10) and booted the USB stick.

I selected in the grub Install Ubuntu, then there was a loading purple screen and suddenly:

```
"No signal"
```

message from monitor and monitor goes off. The PC is still on, but I can't use the monitor. So I need to force the restart.

Why does this happen? I tried also to reset BIOS configuration and disabled the "xmp" profile, so RAM runs at 2133MHz, but there's nothing to do.

I think something related with graphics card because my processor Ryzen 7 2700x doesn't have an integrated graphics card, so maybe it switches to the motherboqard's HDMI port instead of the HDMI port in the dedicated GT 1030.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this with `nomodeset`:

- hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when booting starts.
- You will then get a console mode menu.
- Scroll to `Install Ubuntu`
- Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit that line.
- Move to the end of the line. Delete the text that says `quiet splash`
  and then enter `nomodeset` instead, ensuring there is a space between
  the new option and any other option.
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

After the Ubuntu installation, Ubuntu will reboot. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to enter command prompt. Choose `Ubuntu`. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit commands and once again delete the text that says `quiet splash` and then enter `nomodeset` instead and boot by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>. In Ubuntu go to the "Software and Updates" and download nVidia proprietary drivers.